# SlidingTabLayout setDistributeEvenly missing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using the SlidingTabLayout.java from developers android page. Before I used `slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);` to center the slidingtab but now the method is missing.
What's the alternative? I could use the old java class but I suppose there is an alternative method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your SlidingTabLayout add the following:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
tabView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

just before

```
mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
```

After that you won't even need `slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);`
the tabs will automatically center themselves.